# Displaying georgian date as a hijri date

Tags: android, database, hijri

I created a database for georgian date only. In my android application's home page I want to display both georgian and hijri dates (islamic). How can I write the hijri code?

My georgian code is

```
void getDate()
{
    Date d=new Date();
    CharSequence s  = DateFormat.format("EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy", d.getTime());
    miladiView.setText(s);// the name of the field that displays georgian date 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the IslamicChronology from Joda.org (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/cal_islamic.html). Though not sure how accurate they're doing it, since Hijri date (for example in Saudi) is based on moon sighting (not pure mathematical calculation), which can even differ between different Muslim countries.

An example from the aforementioned source:

```
// setup date object for midday on May Day 2004 (ISO year 2004)
DateTime dtISO = new DateTime(2004, 5, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0);

// find out what the same instant is using the Islamic Chronology
DateTime dtIslamic = dtISO.withChronology(IslamicChronology.getInstance());
```

Comment: the datetime is not defined

Comment: Have you imported it?
    import org.joda.time.*;
    import org.joda.time.chrono.*;

Comment: Or, you can use this code here, which is based on mathematical equations to calculate Hijri date: http://www.coderanch.com/t/534271/java/java/Gregorian-Hijri-Dates-Converter-JAVA